# How to extract client certificate info from OpenVPN?

Tags: python, linux, perl, bash, openvpn

When a user is connected to my OpenVPN server would I like to extract the ID of the clients certificate.

The purpose is to write a script that will prevent users from sharing their certificates with others. Right now any certificate will work with any valid LDAP user.

When I set `script-security 3`, which seams to give the most info to the `env` variable, I see the variables at the bottom of this post (actual values removed). As far as I can tell, nothing in there can be tied to the certificate the user used.

**Question**

How do I get hold of the client's certificate/key ID, so I can match it against `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/*{.crt,.csr,.key}`? The filename is the LDAP username.

E.g.

```
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/bob.crt
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/bob.csr
/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/bob.key
```

Dump of `env` variable

```
X509_1_OU=
common_name=
route_gateway_1=
ifconfig_remote=
untrusted_ip=
ifconfig_local=
proto_1=
tls_serial_1=
tls_serial_0=
tun_mtu=
X509_1_emailAddress=
tls_id_0=
X509_1_L=
tls_id_1=
X509_1_O=
password=
script_type=
verb=
username=
local_port_1=
config=
X509_0_CN=
dev=
auth_control_file=
X509_1_C=
X509_1_ST=
route_network_1=
remote_port_1=
PWD=
route_net_gateway=
daemon=
X509_1_name=
untrusted_port=
SHLVL=
script_context=
route_vpn_gateway=
route_netmask_1=
daemon_start_time=
X509_0_ST=
daemon_pid=
X509_1_CN=
X509_0_OU=
X509_0_emailAddress=
daemon_log_redirect=
X509_0_C=
X509_0_L=
link_mtu=
X509_0_O=
```

Comment: OpenVPN's dumping seems to be faulty. Provide a redacted output of `openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text -noout`. I guess/predict the user name should be extracted from the Common Name part of the subject of the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have removed the actual values from the output, and only kept the variable names. updated the post.

Comment: So, not common_name or username?

Comment: @Ivo : I have now tried to change CN in the clients crt file to something else, and `common_name` is still the same. Does this mean, that `common_name` is encoded in the `crt` file, and the client can't just change/fake this?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting the `crt` is signed by the `key`. You can't change the `crt` without generating a new `csr` and signing it with the `key` again. I'm not an expert authority, so I don't know which, but there should be some fields that the client can't change without breaking the certificate's validation. Looking at the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Structure_of_a_certificate), It would seem to me you can't change the Subject attributes (`CN`, etc).

Comment: @Ivo If you post that as answer, then I will accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crt` is signed by the `key`. You can't change the `crt` without generating a new `csr` and signing it with the `key` again. I'm not an expert authority, so I don't know which, but there should be some fields that the client can't change without breaking the certificate's validation. Looking at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Structure_of_a_certificate) page, It would seem to me you can't change the Subject attributes (`CN`, etc).

So if you're validating user `bob`, with `bob.crt`, then make sure in the certificate the `CN` is bob. Matching all three of these should mean that bob is logging in with his own certificate.